# Delivering email to Maildir PreINBOX

Tags: email, dovecot

I have a running dovecot with:

```
$ dovecot -n
# 2.2.18: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.1.0-x86_64-linode59 x86_64 Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two) ext4
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login digest-md5 cram-md5
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
default_internal_user = root
imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail tb-extra-mailbox-sep
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
maildir_very_dirty_syncs = yes
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  prefix = INBOX.
  separator = .
  type = private
}
namespace inbox {
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = pmatos
protocols = imap
quota_full_tempfail = yes
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-master {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = $default_internal_user
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/home/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
  driver = static
}
protocol lda {
  auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  log_path = /home/vmail/dovecot-deliver.log
}
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 100
}
```

I started to filter my email with imapfilter running on the same host as dovecot. I would therefore like to deliver email to a folder called `PreINBOX` so that imapfilter then sorts the email and ends up delivering only the useful email to `INBOX`.

How can I change the name of the inbox dovecot delivers to?

Comment: Could you name MTA/SMTP server you use? How have you integrated it with dovecot? [one option is to implement you requirement in MTA config]

Comment: Ah, of course... It's not dovecot delivering the email but Postfix. I guess this question is now not about Dovecot but about Postfix.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved by reconfiguring dovecot **OR postfix**.
[ Podtfix is mentioned in your comments ]

One simple fix is to make postfix use `virtual` mailer to deliver new messages to `/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir/.PreINBOX/` maildir.

[Postfix virtual MAILBOX example: separate domains, non-UNIX accounts](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox)
[ Direct delivery by postfix to virtual mailbox/maildir ]

Comment: Can you add more details to your reply please?

Comment: I have added link to the relevant subsection of postfix howto.